# Rspec - Check for the instance of ActiveRecord::Relation of a specific Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-activerecord, rails-upgrade

In our application, we have used this

```
expect_any_instance_of(Order::ActiveRecord_Relation)
  .to receive(:something)
```

As we upgraded the application to rails 5.2 we are getting the following error

```
NameError:
   private constant #<Class:0x000055aa351fc9a0>::ActiveRecord_Relation referenced
```

Is there a way to check for `ActiveRecord::Relation` of a specific Model with `expect_any_instance_of`

There a issue raised for the same https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/30943

Comment: There is clear explanation from core dev, you're trying to access private method. It's not a part of public API, so you can't use it.

Comment: I know, that's why I am asking if there is any way to check the same without using the `Class:>::ActiveRecord_Relation`

Comment: that's probably not the best test expectation, show us the code you're testing and we can give you an alternative perhaps

Answer (score 3):

try this `Order.const_get(:ActiveRecord_Relation)`. it should make it work in rails >= 5.2

Answer (score 0):

```
expect_any_instance_of(Order.const_get(:ActiveRecord_Relation))
  .to receive(:something)
```